# Exporting a web map with Google Maps Satellite using Qgis2Web?

Tags: qgis, google-maps, qgis2web

I am really new to QGis, is it possible on QGis export a map using qgis2web with the Google Map Satellite layers? I tried several times but is not working.

Comment: only exports from google earth (or pro) can exported due to licencing

Answer (score 9):

I'm afraid this isn't possible. Since Google data has licensing implications, I can't run the risk of including them in qgis2web. Very sorry. I would suggest that you find another source of satellite imagery - I don't have one to suggest, though.

Comment: QGIS plugin OpenLayers can add Gooogle's map services to QGIS. Although this is not exactly same case, I wonder why OpenLayers plugin does not violate Google's licensing?